# Remove L parameter in request URL

Tags: solr, parameters, typo3, typo3-9.x

I'm using Solr extension with TYPO3 9.5.3 and I couldn't index the Pages, I get this error https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6XtA.jpg

```
Failed to execute Page Indexer Request. Request ID: 5d78d130b8b4d
```

When I look at the Solr log, I see that Typo3 add `&L=0` to the request URL, the pages with `&L=0` return '404 page not found' error :

```
request url => 'http://example.com/index.php?id=5&L=0' (43 chars)
```

I added the following code to my TS setup, But that did not work and the request url always ends with `&L=0`

```
plugin.tx_solr.index.queue.pages.fields.url.typolink.additionalParams >
```

I'm not sure that's the only reason solr doesn't index the pages (news can be indexed without any problem), but first, how can I solve the problem and remove `&L=0` from request URL in Solr ?

Comment: You should update to the newest version of TYPO3, currently it's 9.5.9. About the `&L=0`, that can come from a TypoScript-Menu - then it would be based on individual setup. It's also possible that the parameter is not added by TYPO3 but by a `.htaccess` file or other kind of server-configuration.

Comment: I don't know exactly the indexing process of solr, but if it's just crawling the pages like a user would do then you could rewrite urls and remove the parameter '&L=0' in a `.htaccess` file or other kind of server-configuration if there are problems to remove it in TYPO3. This is not really recommended, it should be possible in TYPO3 and therefore is the last work-around to use.

Comment: For more detailed help it's useful to know how the urls are generated (by TypoScript or by a content-element of type menu or somehow else).

Comment: On frontend pages, I dont have `&L=0` I have realURL enabled ... `&L=0` this param display only for solr request url

Comment: with realUrl you're covering all or many parameters. You should consider switching it off for an analysis. If switching off: make a sitemap of the pages and perhaps some extension views, then you can switch realUrl on again. If you've a local installation of the page you can do it there.

Comment: @David realurl isn't a thing anymore with TYPO3 9. This kind of configuration should lay inside a site configuration now. Basically if this configuration exists, there shouldn't be any need for the L parameter anymore. Links generated by TYPO3 will respect that and replace the L parameter on its own, so my guess is, that there is some stuff at work here, that builds links without TYPO3, which is bad regardless.

Comment: @KevinDitscheid goodstuff mentioned realUrl, so I answered on that. Concerning the seo-extension I don't know exactly how it's done concerning sever-requests as it works even without any rewriting by `.htaccess` or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check your TypoScript if you have a configuration like
 `config.defaultGetVars.L = 0`
or if other old language settings exist

Answer (score 0):

I

1. m not dure, but have you an older languge-Configuration where you Deine the language-Parameter deines?